# Why MySQL don't return result?

Tags: mysql

Execute queries:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO log_table (order_sum) VALUES (100)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
COMMIT
```

Then, after some time (a few minutes) execute querу:

```
SELECT order_sum FROM log_table WHERE order_id = $order_id
```

$order_id equal result from LAST_INSERT_ID()

But mysql_num_rows() return 0.
If you run the query manually - row exists. 
This is not observed every request (every few requests)

What could it be?

Comment: If $order_id equals LAST_INSERT_ID() then I really don't understand the point of this sproc.

Comment: These are two different script. First is create an order. The second is the callback, check and give item.

Comment: So, the session owner might carry out INSERTs on other tables in between the sproc and the select?